# Return a list of all strings matching a regex from another string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in my table with the value below in one of the tuple:

```
<p>&nbsp;<element id=\"16342123118940031\"></element>&nbsp;&nbsp;<element id=\"16342123118940033\"></element>&nbsp;&nbsp;<element id=\"16342123162580033\"></element>&nbsp;&nbsp;<element id=\"16342123187750034\"></element>&nbsp;</p>"
```

I want to run a query on one of those tuples and fetch a list of all strings inside the tuple which are matching a specific regex.

Say I want all strings starting with `<element` and ending with `</element>`. For this I have a regex `<element [^<element]+</element>`. The query should then return me a list of the strings in the tuple matching this  regex. For the above Value/Tuple, the query should return:

```
<element id=\"16342123118940031\"></element>
<element id=\"16342123118940033\"></element>
<element id=\"16342123162580033\"></element>
<element id=\"16342123187750034\"></element>
```

How can I achieve this using SQL?

Thank you.

Comment: So to make it clear: You have *one* column, which value is a string like `<element ...></element><element ...></element> ...` and you want to return a resultset where each of these `<element>..</element>` is a single row. Ie you want your query to split a single cell value to return multiple rows?

Comment: A single cell value can contain multiple-element tags, I want to take all of them out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could convert this to XML and use XQuery.

Your only issue is converting the `&nbsp;` non-breaking-space to the correct XML version `&#160;`.

> I've assumed the `\"` in the question is just string escaping from some client code, and isn't actually in the column

```sql
SELECT x.elem.value('@id','nvarchar(100)')
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    CAST(REPLACE(t.YourHtml, N'&nbsp;', N'&#160;') AS xml)
)) v(xml)
CROSS APPLY v.xml.nodes('p/element') x(elem);
```

If you didn't know what the name of the attribute was, you can pull that out too:

```sql
SELECT x.elem.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(100)'), x.elem.value('.','nvarchar(100)')
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    CAST(REPLACE(t.YourHtml, N'&nbsp;', N'&#160;') AS xml)
)) v(xml)
CROSS APPLY v.xml.nodes('p/element/@*') x(elem);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=46cf85976f401f9b7d95b518b2a2e004)